# PHP: class function works in one file but not another

Tags: php, regex, telegram

I am making a Telegram Bot using PHP. I have bot.php, filter.php and test.php.

I want my bot to send a message to the user that includes an ID.
I have a Filter class and I have a function in my filter.php with a regex pattern to detect this id and I'm using preg_match to obtain the match.

```
public function getID($string) {
    $pattern = "/e0(\d){6}\b/i";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}
```

In my test.php, I use that function and it was able to echo the match to me.

```
<?php
include __DIR__ . './filter.php';
$check = new Filter();    
$pattern = "/e0(\d){6}\b/i";
$text = "hi e0000000";
echo "id: ".$check->getID($text);
?>
```

In my bot.php, I try to use the same function to send a message, but it doesn't work. (the sendMsg function is just a simple curl http request to the Telegram Bot API)

```
include __DIR__ . './filter.php';
$filter = new Filter();
function handleGoodMessage($chatId, $text) {
  $report = "Message '".$text."' passed the filters.\nID: ".$filter->getID($text);
  sendMsg($chatId, $report);
}
```

Instead, whenever the function is called the bot returns a 500 Internal Server Error.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$filter` is not accessible inside the function.

```
$filter = new Filter(); //<--- filter is here, in the outer scope
function handleGoodMessage($chatId, $text) {
  $report = "Message '".$text."' passed the filters.\nID: ".$filter->getID($text); 
  
  //this scope is inside the function, $filter does not exist here
  sendMsg($chatId, $report);
}
```

This works in test as you do not change the scope.  You need to pass `$filter` in

------UPDATE----

personally I would always rely on injection rather than using `globals` so my preference would be to redefine the function like this:

```
function handleGoodMessage($chatId, $text, $filter) {
      $report = "Message '".$text."' passed the filters.\nID: ".$filter->getID($text); 
      sendMsg($chatId, $report);
    }
```

I would probably (at the risk of upsetting some people) have `getID` defined as a `static function` because it's not really interacting anything, not using any member variables and is just processing a string and returning it.  So then instead of injecting it, or using `global` you could say

```
function handleGoodMessage($chatId, $text) {
      $report = "Message '".$text."' passed the filters.\nID: ".Filter::getID($text); 
      sendMsg($chatId, $report);
    }
```

Comment: so i need to add ```global $filter;``` inside the function?

Comment: @Jerryl  I would not recommend using `global`, using globals is usually a sign of a bad design pattern.  I've expanded my answer for you, but I would recommend doing some more research about scope